# Why scripts and CSS tags loaded before <DOCTYPE>?

Tags: html

Whilst I was looking upon this [bootsnip](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/exR5v) I noticed that the HTML and CSS are loaded BEFORE `<DOCTYPE>` HTML tag. Thus this made me wonder why the author did that.

For reference the first lines of the bootsnip's html code are:

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->


<!DOCTYPE html><html class=''>
<head><script src='//production-assets.codepen.io/assets/editor/live/console_runner-079c09a0e3b9ff743e39ee2d5637b9216b3545af0de366d4b9aad9dc87e26bfd.js'></script><script src='//production-assets.codepen.io/assets/editor/live/events_runner-73716630c22bbc8cff4bd0f07b135f00a0bdc5d14629260c3ec49e5606f98fdd.js'></script><script src='//production-assets.codepen.io/assets/editor/live/css_live_reload_init-2c0dc5167d60a5af3ee189d570b1835129687ea2a61bee3513dee3a50c115a77.js'></script><meta charset='UTF-8'><meta name="robots" content="noindex"><link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="//production-assets.codepen.io/assets/favicon/favicon-8ea04875e70c4b0bb41da869e81236e54394d63638a1ef12fa558a4a835f1164.ico" /><link rel="mask-icon" type="" href="//production-assets.codepen.io/assets/favicon/logo-pin-f2d2b6d2c61838f7e76325261b7195c27224080bc099486ddd6dccb469b8e8e6.svg" color="#111" /><link rel="canonical" href="https://codepen.io/emilcarlsson/pen/ZOQZaV?limit=all&page=74&q=contact+" />
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,600,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Do you know why is a show like that?

Comment: Just visited. There is no such a thing. Make sure you are looking it where it is. It starts with `<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"><head>`

Comment: Also, try to disable all the plugins in your browser or try another browser.

Comment: Perhaps the EFF's privacy badger does this.

Comment: I don't think this is what's actually happening -- I think he is getting his stuff from that first script tag in the head (it's a link to codepen), and you are supposed to copy the stuff at the top of the page.